# How to create my own CacheStore with Ignite to store value in Binary mode (setStoreKeepBinary(true))

Tags: scala, slick, ignite

I would like to create my own CacheStore using Slick to store data value in BinaryMode in a Postgres DB.
I have read the doc related to [Binary Marshaller](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller) on Ignite Website.
I have been inspired by the code here https://github.com/gastonlucero/ignite-persistence/blob/master/src/main/scala/test/db/CachePostgresSlickStore.scala

So I have created that code :

```
val myCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration[String, MySpecialCustomObject]("MYCACHE")
myCacheCfg.setStoreKeepBinary(true)
myCacheCfg.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(classOf[myCacheSlickStore]))
myCacheCfg.setBackups(1)
myCacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.LOCAL)
myCacheCfg.setReadThrough(true)
myCacheCfg.setWriteThrough(true)

.......

class myCacheSlickStore extends CacheStoreAdapter[String, MySpecialCustomObject] with PostgresSlickConnection with Serializable {.....}

......

trait PostgresSlickConnection extends PostgresSlickParameters {

  val tableName: String
}
```

But I have this kind of error : "type mismatch;" for the line related to setCacheStoreFactory

Do you have any idea or example in order to create your own CacheStore with setStoreKeepBinary(true)?

---

```
Here a complete example to illustrate :

final case class myObject(
  parameters_1: Map[String, Set[String]],
  parameters_2: Map[String, Set[String]]
)

class CacheSlickStore extends CacheStoreAdapter[String, BinaryObject] {}


val JdbcPersistence =
      "myJdbcPersistence" 
val cacheCfg =
      new CacheConfiguration[String, myObject](JdbcPersistence)
cacheCfg.setStoreKeepBinary(true) 
cacheCfg.setCacheStoreFactory(
      FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(classOf[CacheSlickStore])
)
cacheCfg.setBackups(1)
cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.LOCAL)
cacheCfg.setReadThrough(true)
cacheCfg.setWriteThrough(true)

var cache: IgniteCache[String, myObject] = _

val config = new IgniteConfiguration()

ignition = Ignition.getOrStart(config)

cache = ignition.getOrCreateCache[String, myObject](JdbcPersistence)
ignition.addCacheConfiguration(cacheCfg)
```

If I cast CacheConfiguration it compiles but fails to run.

Comment: I guess you will need to cast CacheConfiguration to `[String, BinaryObject]`

Comment: I tried before that but it does not work

Comment: Please put a reproducer somewhere so that we can check.

Comment: I have added a new example to illustrate

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Scala tooling set up so I can't try it. Anything runnable from the cmdline? gradle, etc

Comment: No unfortunately. Do you have an example in Java that illustrates how tu have a "normal" cache and a CacheStore with BinaryObject?

Comment: Well, there's the test: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/test/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/GridCacheStoreValueBytesSelfTest.java

Comment: You can find a repository of my code here: https://github.com/fbvdka/ignite-persistence
It does not compile due to error line 27 in https://github.com/fbvdka/ignite-persistence/blob/master/src/main/scala/test/nodes/TestPostgresSlickBinaryPersistence.scala

Comment: I have changed to Any in my code and now it compiles but I got some error 
To test I launch a database with docker 
`docker run --name db-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 -d postgres:11`

Comment: It seems to work but I needed to add in VM arguments `--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution is to cast in scala to Any and not BinaryObject. You can find a solution here [Github project](https://github.com/fbvdka/ignite-persistence/blob/master/src/main/scala/test/nodes/TestPostgresSlickBinaryPersistence.scala)

Comment: Actually, it does not work completely because the way to get byte values to store in a blob in postgres does not work. 
How can we get byte values of BinaryObject?

Comment: Try `((Message)binObj).writeTo()`